# How to change PDF pagination in Linux

Tags: linux, pdf

I have several PDF files in which the page images start with lower case roman page numbers (Table of contents, etc.) and then start with arabic page 1 when the content begins.  In both Evince and Okular, if I type 'iv' into the page number box the docment goes to the page which has "iv" on it.  Similarly if I type '5' it goes to the page which has "5".

Multiple times per year I receive theses to review, often scanned.  In the images they have similar page numbering but '1' takes me to "i" and '5' takes me to "1", for example. I would like to change the PDF so when I type '1' I get taken to page "1" and to go to page "iii" I would type 'iii'. This would make it much quicker for me to move around them more accurately during defenses.

Adobe Acrobat has the ability to renumber pages this way, see [these instructions](https://helpx.adobe.com/ie/acrobat/using/manipulating-deleting-renumbering-pdf-pages.html#renumber_pages)

I am looking for software, preferably open source, which runs on linux that can do this. I am comfortable with the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper term for what I want to change is the "page labels".  There are many open source and free ways to change these which are excellently described in [answers to a similar question on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32048/renumber-pages-of-a-pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Not quite a proper solution (nor have I been able to find one either), but my workaround is to chop the pdf into two: the intro with numerals and the rest of the document with numbers such that the document and reader page numbers align.